# Java Play: Can't set background image in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

Im currently an intern at a company here in Sweden, and they are using `Java Play` for their projects. So i have been given the task to create a website (my programming skills is not developed enough to do some work for them. This website is just practice). I have programmed a page with a combination of `HTML`, `CSS` `JavaScript`, `Java` and `Jquery`, but i can not figure out how i should set my background. The people at my internship can do it in their own code, but they can't make it work for me.

This is my code in `CSS`:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    background-image:url("..\pictures\road.jpg")
}
```

And in `HTML`:

```
<body background = "..\..\public\pictures\road.jpg">
(a bunch of other stuff)
</body>
```

When i open the code in just `HTML`, the image is shown, but when i open it with `Java Play` (which is required for my work) there is no picture.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: last i checked there was no errors, but now:   Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:9000/assets/pictures/road.jpg' because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable.
..picturesroad.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
road.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
9..picturesroad.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Thunderstruck  Try this <body background = "@routes.Assets.at("public/pictures", "road.jpg")" and let us know if you get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
<body style = 'background: url("/assets/pictures/road.jpg")'>
```

in HTML